# How to initialized an observable for async pipe in the template trying to mimic an assignation in the subscription?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, async-pipe

The current code is trying to use the async pipe approach instead of using an assignation in the subscription. But if the delay is happeing in the service, the initial value is not rendering in the template, when the data is ready the value is rendering as expected, I am trying to mimic the rendeing behavior that is presented when I am using this ***this.title2***.

The component:

```
title$: Observable<string> = of('Default Title'); // I am not sure if this assignation is right
title2 = 'Default Title 2';

constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {}

// Load title has a delay in the response
this.title$ = this.sampleService.loadTitle();

this.sampleService.loadTitle().subscribe((title) => {
  this.title2 = title; // the assignation 
});
```

The template:

```
<h4>{{ title$ | async }}</h4>
<h4>{{ title2 }}</h4>
```

[The sample is in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhpvpb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcontainer%2Fcontainer.component.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use [startWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) that do an initialvalue of an observable.
Try to change the code to this, and it works.

```
  this.title$ = this.sampleService
      .loadTitle()
      .pipe(startWith('Default Title'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to this, but given the code you have provided, you could use the `switchMap` operator as follows:

Update `this.title$ = this.sampleService.loadTitle();` to `this.title$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.sampleService.loadTitle()));`

What you are doing currently is overwriting the title$ property with a different value. `switchMap` makes it so that every time the first observable emits a value(in your case this only happens once with your `of('Default Title')`) it will turn around and create another observable which it will then observe for emitted values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-container to subscribe to your observable and rename it so that when the data is ready, you can simply use it as a regular variable in the template.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4f77tz?file=src/app/components/container/container.component.ts)

**container.component.ts**

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  items$: Observable<string[]>;
  title$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title$ = this.sampleService.loadTitle();
    this.items$ = this.sampleService.loadItems();
  }
}
```

**container.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="title$ | async as title">
  <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
  <list *ngIf="items.length" [items]="items"></list>
</ng-container>
```

Keep in mind that wherever you use the word async, it's a new subscription.

If you use async pipe on the same observable multiple times in your template, you are creating multiple subscriptions.

Using the startWith operator is also a good option if you want to have a different starting value than the one from your service call. A good place to use startWith would be for a formControl valueChanges observable since it doesn't have a starting value and only triggers when there is a value changed.